# Why is my XSLTProcessor transformToDocument not working?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xmlhttprequest, domparser

I have been tasked with fixing up an old site to make it compatible with modern browsers. There are some 3rd party controls that are giving me some fits though, and I am not going to pay to get the latest versions of these controls. One of these old grids has some build in javascript that does not work when dealing with XSLTProcessor transformToDocument. This is all compiled JS which I can replace with hopefully some working code. The code that it uses for IE is different and works, but does not work in other browsers. The code for other browsers, which is what I need to fix, is as follows. I will add screenshots of my console log below. The transformToDocument is pretty much returning a blank page. Let me know if I should add anything else to make my issue more clear.

```
    var xmlResp = new DOMParser();
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", xsltURL, false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    this.Processor = new XSLTProcessor();
    this.Processor.importStylesheet(xmlResp.parseFromString(xmlHttp.responseText, "text/xml"));

    console.log(this.Processor.transformToDocument(this.input));           

    this.outputDocument = this.Processor.transformToDocument(this.input);
    var output = this.outputDocument.firstChild.innerHTML;
    if (!output)
        output = "<tbody></tbody>";
    return output;
```

Just for reference, the WORKING IE Code is along these lines

```
    var xslt = ig_createActiveXFromProgIDs(["MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument", "Microsoft.FreeThreadedXMLDOM"]);
    xslt.async = false;
    xslt.load(xsltURL);

    var xslTemplate = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XSLTemplate");
    xslTemplate.stylesheet = xslt;
    this.Processor = xslTemplate.createProcessor();
    this.Processor.input = this.input;
    this.Processor.transform();
    return this.Processor.output;
```

XSLT file from xsltURL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
Version 9.1.20091.2101
Copyright (c) 2001-2009 Infragistics, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="columnIndex" match="Column" use="@index"/>
<xsl:key name="cellIndex" match="C" use="position()"/>

<xsl:variable name="gridName" select="//UltraWebGrid/@id"/>
<xsl:variable name="useFixedHeaders" select="//UltraWebGrid/UltraGridLayout/@UseFixedHeaders"/>
<xsl:variable name="tableLayout" select="//UltraWebGrid/UltraGridLayout/@TableLayout"/>
<xsl:variable name="isXhtml" select="//UltraWebGrid/UltraGridLayout/@IsXhtml"/>
<xsl:variable name="fixedScrollLeft" select="//UltraWebGrid/UltraGridLayout/@fixedScrollLeft"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Rs" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Rs">
    <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="R">
            <xsl:with-param name="bandNo" select="@bandNo"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="parentRowLevel" select="@parentRowLevel"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Group">
            <xsl:with-param name="bandNo" select="@bandNo"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="parentRowLevel" select="@parentRowLevel"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </tbody>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="R">
    <xsl:param name="bandNo"/>
    <xsl:param name="parentRowLevel"/>

    <xsl:variable name="band" select="//UltraWebGrid/Bands/Band[number($bandNo)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fac" select="number($band/@fac)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rs" select="number($band/@rs)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rowIndex" select="@i"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rHeight">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@height">
                <xsl:value-of select="@height" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@rowHeight" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <tr id="{$gridName}_r_{$parentRowLevel}{$rowIndex}" level="{$parentRowLevel}{$rowIndex}">
        <xsl:if test="$band/@optSelectRow">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$rowIndex mod 2 = 1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$band/@altClass" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$band/@itemClass" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:if test="@hidden">display:none;</xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('height:',$rHeight,';')" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="$fac>1 or $rs=2 and $fac=1">
            <th class="{$band/@expAreaClass}">
                <xsl:attribute name="height">
                     <xsl:value-of select="$rHeight"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="img">
                    <xsl:attribute name="border">0</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@showExpand">
                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@expandImage" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                              <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@xAlt"/>
                              </xsl:attribute>
                              <xsl:attribute name="igAltC">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@cAlt"/>
                              </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="imgType">expand</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@blankImage" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="imgType">blank</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="style">visibility:hidden;</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:element>
            </th>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$fac>0 and $rs!=2">
            <th id="{$gridName}_l_{$parentRowLevel}{$rowIndex}" class="{$band/@rowLabelClass}">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;<xsl:if test="@rowSelectStyle"><xsl:value-of select="@rowSelectStyle" disable-output-escaping="yes" />;</xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="$band/@rowHeight">height:<xsl:value-of select="$band/@rowHeight" disable-output-escaping="yes" />;</xsl:if>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@rowNumber">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@rowNumber" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:element name="img">
                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@rowLabelBlankImage" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="alt"></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="border">0</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="imgType">blank</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </th>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Cs">
            <xsl:with-param name="band" select="$band"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="rowIndex" select="$rowIndex" />
            <xsl:with-param name="row" select="." />
            <xsl:with-param name="rowHeight" select="$rHeight" />
            <xsl:with-param name="parentRowLevel" select="$parentRowLevel" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cs">
    <xsl:param name="band"/>
    <xsl:param name="rowIndex" />
    <xsl:param name="row" />
    <xsl:param name="rowHeight" />
    <xsl:param name="parentRowLevel"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$band/Columns/Column">
        <xsl:if test="not(@grouped) and not(@serverOnly) and not(@nonfixed)">
            <xsl:variable name="columnIndex">
                <xsl:value-of select="@cellIndex"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="cell" select="$row/Cs/C[number($columnIndex)]"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$rowIndex mod 2 = 1">
                    <xsl:call-template name="cellTemplate">
                        <xsl:with-param name="cell" select="$cell" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="rowIndex" select="$rowIndex" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="className">
                            <xsl:if test="not($band/@optSelectRow)">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@altClass" />
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="rowHeight" select="$rowHeight" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="parentRowLevel" select="$parentRowLevel" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="rowStyle" select="$row/@style" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="rowClass" select="$row/@class" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="cellTemplate">
                        <xsl:with-param name="cell" select="$cell" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="rowIndex" select="$rowIndex" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="className">
                            <xsl:if test="not($band/@optSelectRow)">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@itemClass" />
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="rowHeight" select="$rowHeight" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="parentRowLevel" select="$parentRowLevel" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="rowStyle" select="$row/@style" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="rowClass" select="$row/@class" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:if test="$useFixedHeaders">
        <td colspan="{$band/@nfspan}">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$band/@optSelectRow">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($gridName,'-no')" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:if test="$row/@dtdh">
                        <xsl:attribute name="height">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$row/@dtdh" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$row/@dtdh">
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('vertical-align:top;height:',$row/@dtdh,';')" />
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>vertical-align:top;width:100%;</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <div id="{$gridName}_drs">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$row/@dtdh">overflow:hidden;<xsl:value-of select="$row/@ht"/><xsl:if test="$isXhtml">position:relative;</xsl:if></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%;<xsl:if test="$isXhtml">position:relative;</xsl:if></xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
                    <table width="1"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position:relative;table-layout:fixed;height:100%;{$fixedScrollLeft}">
                        <colgroup>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$band/Columns/Column">
                            <xsl:if test="not(@grouped) and not(@serverOnly) and not(@hidden) and @nonfixed">
                                <col width="{@width}"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$band/Columns/Column">
                            <xsl:if test="not(@grouped) and not(@serverOnly) and @hidden and @nonfixed">
                                <col width="1px" style="display:none;"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </colgroup>
                        <tr id="{$gridName}_nfr_{$parentRowLevel}{$rowIndex}">
                        <xsl:attribute name="style">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$row/@height">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('height:',$row/@height,';')" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('height:',$rowHeight,';')" />
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$band/Columns/Column">
                            <xsl:variable name="columnIndex">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@cellIndex"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:variable name="cell" select="$row/Cs/C[number($columnIndex)]"/>
                            <xsl:if test="not(@grouped) and not(@serverOnly) and @nonfixed">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="$rowIndex mod 2 = 1">
                                        <xsl:call-template name="cellTemplate">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="cell" select="$cell" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="rowIndex" select="$rowIndex" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="className">
                                                <xsl:if test="not($band/@optSelectRow)">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="$band/@altClass" />
                                                </xsl:if>
                                            </xsl:with-param>
                                            <xsl:with-param name="rowHeight" select="$rowHeight" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="parentRowLevel" select="$parentRowLevel" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="rowStyle" select="$row/@style" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="rowClass" select="$row/@class" />
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="cellTemplate">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="cell" select="$cell" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="rowIndex" select="$rowIndex" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="className">
                                                <xsl:if test="not($band/@optSelectRow)">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="$band/@itemClass" />
                                                </xsl:if>
                                            </xsl:with-param>
                                            <xsl:with-param name="rowHeight" select="$rowHeight" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="parentRowLevel" select="$parentRowLevel" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="rowStyle" select="$row/@style" />
                                            <xsl:with-param name="rowClass" select="$row/@class" />
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="cellTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="cell" />
    <xsl:param name="rowIndex" />
    <xsl:param name="className" />
    <xsl:param name="rowHeight" />
    <xsl:param name="parentRowLevel"/>
    <xsl:param name="rowStyle"/>
    <xsl:param name="rowClass"/>

    <xsl:if test="not($cell/@merged)">

        <xsl:variable name="cellIndex">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()-1"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <td id="{$gridName}_rc_{$parentRowLevel}{$rowIndex}_{$cellIndex}">
            <xsl:if test="$cell/@rowSpan">
                <xsl:attribute name="rowSpan">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$cell/@rowSpan" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$cell/@colSpan">
                <xsl:attribute name="colSpan">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$cell/@colSpan" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$cell/@title">
                <xsl:attribute name="title">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$cell/@title" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="string-length($className)>0 or ./@class or $rowClass or $cell/@class">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($className,' ',./@class,' ',$rowClass,' ',$cell/@class)" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="./@style or $rowStyle or $cell/@style or @hidden">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(./@style,$rowStyle,$cell/@style)" />
                    <xsl:if test="@hidden">display:none;</xsl:if>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$cell/@allowedit">
                <xsl:attribute name="allowedit">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$cell/@allowedit" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$cell/@uV">
                <xsl:attribute name="uV">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$cell/@uV" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$cell/@iCT">
                <xsl:attribute name="iCT">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$cell/@iCT" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$cell/@iDV">
                <xsl:attribute name="iDV">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$cell/@iDV" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$cell/@iTM">
                <xsl:attribute name="iTM">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$cell/@iTM" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$cell/@br"><xsl:if test="$cell/@doe"><xsl:attribute name="name">_igdoe</xsl:attribute></xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="$cell" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><nobr><xsl:if test="$cell/@doe"><xsl:attribute name="name">_igdoe</xsl:attribute></xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="$cell" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></nobr></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </td>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Group">
    <xsl:param name="bandNo"/>
    <xsl:param name="parentRowLevel"/>

    <xsl:variable name="band" select="//UltraWebGrid/Bands/Band[number($bandNo)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rowIndex" select="@i"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rHeight">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@height">
                <xsl:value-of select="@height" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@rowHeight" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <tr id="{$gridName}_gr_{$parentRowLevel}{$rowIndex}" groupRow="{@groupRow}" level="{$parentRowLevel}{$rowIndex}">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">height:<xsl:value-of select="$rHeight" />;<xsl:if test="$isXhtml and $useFixedHeaders">position:relative;</xsl:if></xsl:attribute>
        <td>
            <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' bgcolor='{@bgcolor}' bandNo='{@bandNo}'>
                <xsl:if test="$tableLayout">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style">table-layout:fixed;</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="../@grpWidth" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></xsl:attribute>
                <tr id="{$gridName}_sgr_{$parentRowLevel}{$rowIndex}" level="{$parentRowLevel}{$rowIndex}" groupRow="{@groupRow}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style">height:<xsl:value-of select="$rHeight" />;</xsl:attribute>
                    <td id="{$gridName}_grc_{$parentRowLevel}{$rowIndex}" groupRow="{@groupRow}" style='{@style}' class='{$band/@grpClass}'>
                        <xsl:attribute name="cellValue">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@cellValue" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:element name="img">
                            <xsl:attribute name="border">0</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@expandImage" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@xAlt"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="igAltC">
                <xsl:value-of select="$band/@cAlt"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="imgType">expand</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:text>&#xa0;&#xa0;</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@content" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<Rs bandNo="1" parentRowLevel="">
    <R DataKey="10521" i="0">
        <Cs>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[10521]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[CHARLEBOIS, CHRIS-(9080)]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[PT Server]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[EillenStaffType]]>
            </C>
            <C style="background-color:Silver;" doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C style="background-color:Silver;" doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C style="background-color:Silver;" doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C style="background-color:Silver;" doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C style="background-color:Silver;" doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C style="background-color:Silver;" doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
        </Cs>
    </R>
    <R DataKey="10522" i="1">
        <Cs>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[10522]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[CURRAN, COLLEEN-(1663)]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[PT Server]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[Food and Beverage]]>
            </C>
            <C iTM="1" style="background-color:Silver;" doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C iTM="1" style="background-color:Silver;" doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C iTM="1" style="background-color:Silver;" doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C iTM="1" title="Date requested: 11/9/2012  " style="background-color:Silver;"
            doe="1">
                <![CDATA[<Table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="vertical-align:middle;width:100%;height:100%"><tr style="width:100%"><td NOWRAP class="SDCP" style=";height:20px;display=block"    pa="Unable to find IndirectType()." pt="Unable to find IndirectType()." ><span>Unable to find IndirectType().</span></td></tr></Table>]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C iTM="1" title="Date requested: 11/9/2012  " style="background-color:Silver;"
            doe="1">
                <![CDATA[<Table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="vertical-align:middle;width:100%;height:100%"><tr style="width:100%"><td NOWRAP class="SDCP" style=";height:20px;display=block"    pa="Unable to find IndirectType()." pt="Unable to find IndirectType()." ><span>Unable to find IndirectType().</span></td></tr></Table>]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C iTM="1" style="background-color:Silver;" doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
            <C doe="1">
                <![CDATA[&nbsp;]]>
            </C>
        </Cs>
    </R>
</Rs>
```

Console screen (this.Processor.transformToDocument(this.input) ):

[image: transformToDocument]

Comment: I am guessing there is something wrong with the XSLT file or the XML, i just am not familiar with this technology so I thought I would throw it up on here as I start to dig in. The control in question is the infragistics ultrawebgrid which has since been discontinued. The code is taken out of its compiled js and pieced together from several functions, but is pretty much exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT doesn't get the right MIME type, which might cause the failure. Maybe try the following changes:

```
var xmlResp = new DOMParser();
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", xsltURL, false);
// Make sure the returned document has the correct MIME type
xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("application/xslt+xml");
xmlHttp.send(null);
this.Processor = new XSLTProcessor();
// Just interpret the returned data as XML instead of parsing in a separate step
this.Processor.importStylesheet(xmlHttp.responseXML);

console.log(xmlResp.responseXML);
console.log(this.input);
console.log(this.Processor.transformToDocument(this.input));           


this.outputDocument = this.Processor.transformToDocument(this.input);
var output = this.outputDocument.firstChild.innerHTML;
if (!output)
    output = "<tbody></tbody>";
return output;
```

Comment: hmmmm no dice... Still the same html returned. Let me know if I can add anything to the question to help

Comment: What kind of output do you expect? An HTML document?

Comment: not a full html page, but html yes, let me replace that image with the actual full XSLT file to show what should be happening. Its a huge one though so it might not let me

Comment: OK i added the full xslt file from the control. This item might be not worth the trouble. I might end up just replacing this UltraWebGrid with a standard control. It doent look like anything too facny is being done with it. I was just hoping I could make a little tweak to the imbedded JS and get it working.

Comment: If you can also post the input document there will be less guessing involved.

Comment: Your stylesheet actually doesn't do a lot with your document. Is this really a complete document? There are elements that the stylesheet assumes to be there that actually aren't.

Comment: there was like 15 more <R></R> blocks but thats just extra rows of the data I am playing with. Thats the full xml with just most of the row items removed. No unique xml is missing

Comment: it seems like there is just too much going on as far as params back and forth to even worry about. Thanks for your help though. I am just going to replace this control with a standard one. There is probably a reason that infragistics discontinued it years ago.