# How to correctly use the XSLTProcessor to fill out a table (or add a stand-alone element) to an existing html page?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I am trying to load a table using XSLT on a user's command on Safari and Firefox. I am still a beginner, but have had success creating a complete document from the transformation (HTML tags in the XSL file) as opposed to here where I am trying to only supplement a portion of the document (`thead` and `tbody` tags are in the XSL file to be appended on the `table` tags in the HTML file).

The code below is my attempt so far (this is a simplified example of my project). When the XSL output method is set to "HTML" or "XHTML" the output appears to be similar to a string. When it is "XML", the output is at least somewhat formatted, though still not in what I expected as an HTML table.

**XML: (test.xml)**

```
<people>
    <person personID="1054">
        <info>
            <name>
                <first>Mathew</first>
                <last>Johnson</last>
            </name>
            <phone>5550446932</phone>
            <address>
                <street>5555 NW Terrygold Place</street>
                <city>Davis</city>
                <state>California</state>
            </address>
            <email>glennjohnson@email.com</email>
        </info>
    </person>
    <person personID="1055">
        <info>
            <name>
                <first>Elizabeth</first>
                <last>Johnson</last>
            </name>
            <phone>5553542932</phone>
            <address>
                <street>5555 NW Terrygold Place</street>
                <city>Davis</city>
                <state>California</state>
            </address>
            <email>glennjohnson@email.com</email>
        </info>
    </person>
    <person personID="1056">
            <info>
                <name>
                    <first>Bernhardt</first>
                    <last>Johnson</last>
                </name>
                <phone>5554195424</phone>
                <address>
                    <street>5555 NW Terrygold Place</street>
                    <city>Davis</city>
                    <state>California</state>
                </address>
                <email>mathewjohnson@email.com</email>
            </info>
    </person>
        <person personID="1057">
            <info>
                <name>
                    <first>Robert</first>
                    <last>Loblaw</last>
                </name>
                <phone>5554186971</phone>
                <address>
                    <street>5555 Ramona Dr</street>
                    <city>Newport Beach</city>
                    <state>California</state>
                </address>
                <email>bobloblaw@email.com</email>
            </info>
    </person>
            <person personID="1058">
            <info>
                <name>
                    <first>Evelynn</first>
                    <last>Widowmaker</last>
                </name>
                <phone>5551545638</phone>
                <address>
                    <street>5555 Shadow Isles</street>
                    <city>Portland</city>
                    <state>Oregon</state>
                </address>
                <email>op@email.com</email>
            </info>
    </person>
</people>
```

**XSL: (test.xsl)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tbody>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="person">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(info/name/first, ' ', info/name/last)"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="info/address/state"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="info/phone"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML: (test.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example XSLT Table</title>
<style>

body {
    cursor : default;
}

table {
    width : 400px;
    height : 300px;
    border : solid;
}


</style>
</head>
    <body>


<input id="examplebutton" type="submit" value="Load Table">

<table id="exampletable">
</table>




<footer></footer>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var xml = loadX("test.xml");
var xsltTable = loadX("test.xsl");
var button = document.getElementById("examplebutton");
var table = document.getElementById("exampletable");
var useAX = (window.ActiveXObject)? true : false;

button.addEventListener("click", function () {loadTable();}, false);


function loadTable() {
    var output = getStyledXML(xml, xsltTable);
    table.innerHTML = "";
    table.appendChild(output);
}


function loadX (fileName) {
    var xhttpR;
    if (useAX) {
        xhttpR = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");//I have little to no ie experience (and haven't tried this yet), so this may not make any sense.
    }
    else {
        xhttpR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xhttpR.open("GET", fileName, false);
    xhttpR.send(null);
    return(xhttpR.responseXML);
}

function getStyledXML (data, style) {
    var result;

    if (useAX) {
        result = data.transformNode(style);
    }
    else {
        var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(style);
        result = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(data, document);
    }


    return(result);
}




</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have looked over [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations) [two](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_XSLT_JavaScript_Interface_in_Gecko/JavaScript_XSLT_Bindings) pages covering the xslt processor and JS and have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976406/why-is-my-xsltprocessor-transformtodocument-not-working) that is similar. However I still am unable to get this to work. Sometimes their information is outdated, but I have also looked over/used the w3schools example (link in a comment below) on transforming on the client.

Sorry for the length of this post--I know I still have a lot to learn, so I appreciate any guidance towards a solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: w3schools example [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I think with Mozilla respectively Firefox your attempt is mostly fine in terms of Javascript and XSLT and the use of the XSLTProcessor API, only if you want to style a table with CSS then you need to make sure you style it completely or be lazy like me and use the `frame` and `rules` attribute.

Doing that http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2013120601.html works fine for me with Firefox 25. I also edited the script code to use IE's MSXML API, then the example also works fine with IE 10, I am not sure about older versions, test yourself.

As for Google Chrome, it indeed seems to have a problem generating a fragment of HTML nodes like `thead` and `tbody`, for reasons I don't understand the fragment returned by `transformToFragment` only contains text. Someone else will need to help on this.